# Mutiline a random string

Tags: c#

I am a novice in this programming language so now I have a few problems. I have a bill where I need it to find the "/" character and then the string must be automatically carriage return
For example, I have the following string of characters:

```
BL4444 / BL5555 / BL6666
```

I need it to be:

```
BL4444 /
BL5555 /
BL6666
```

Comment: My answer has been updated according to your last comment

Answer (score 2):

Replace `/`  (slash and space) with `/` and new line:

[String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0) and [Environment.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-5.0):

```
var str = "BL4444 / BL5555 / BL6666";

str = str.Replace("/ ", "/" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Like i have that string on a bill and i need it to count then it found "/" character and it will automatically carriage return

Comment: @DuVoQuoc if you didn't add it to the original question, its not really fair to keep changing the rules once you have asked